# Detecting touching a SKSpriteNode within a touchesBegan event?

Tags: touchesbegan

**Detecting touching a SKSpriteNode within a touchesBegan event?**

My experience to date has focused on using GamepadControllers with Apps, **not** a touch-activated iOS App.

Here are some short code snippets:

Note: the error I am trying to correct is noted in the very first snippet = `touchesBegan` within the comment **<== shows "horse"**

Yes, there is a "horse", but it is no where near the "creditsInfo" `SKSpriteNode` within my `.sks`file =

[image]

Please note that this "creditsInfo" `SKSpriteNode` is programmatically generated by my `addCreditsButton(..)` and will be placed very near the top-left of my `GameScene`.

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    if let ourScene = GameScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") {
        
        if let touch:UITouch = touches.first {
            let location = touch.location(in: view)
            let node:SKNode = ourScene.atPoint(location)
            
            print("node.name = \(node.name!)")   // <== shows "horse"
            if (node.name == "creditsInfo") {
                showCredits()
            }
        }
        
    }   // if let ourScene
    
}   // touchesBegan
```

The above `touchesBegan` function is an `extension GameViewController` which according to the docs is okay, namely, `touchesBegan` is a `UIView` method besides being a `UIViewController` method.

Within my primary `showScene()` function, I have:

```
    if let ourScene = GameScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") {

#if os(iOS)
    addCreditsButton(toScene: ourScene)
#endif

     }
```

with:

```
func addCreditsButton(toScene: SKScene) {
            
    if thisSceneName == "GameScene" {
                    
        itsCreditsNode.name = "creditsInfo"

        itsCreditsNode.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
        
        itsCreditsNode.size = CGSize(width: 2*creditsCircleRadius,
                                     height: 2*creditsCircleRadius)
        itsCreditsNode.zPosition = 3
        creditsCirclePosY = roomHeight/2 - creditsCircleRadius - creditsCircleOffsetY
        creditsCirclePosX = -roomWidth/2 + creditsCircleRadius + creditsCircleOffsetX
        itsCreditsNode.position = CGPoint(x: creditsCirclePosX,
                                          y: creditsCirclePosY)
        
        toScene.addChild(itsCreditsNode)
                    
    }   // if thisSceneName

}   // addCreditsButton
```

To finish, I repeat what I stated at the very top:

The error I am trying to correct is noted in the very first snippet = `touchesBegan` within the comment **<== shows "horse"**

Comment: I did check my `.zPosition` numbers and they were okay. I even set its `.zPosition` to a crazy 20 - **no change**. I also checked that `node.isHidden = false` and it is. So, it appears that someone else's statement = `location` is the culprit.  As a matter of interest, this "info" `SKSpriteNode` is physically very close to the top-left corner .. so I clicked very close to this location and got, for example (1.0, 30.0). No matter how precise I tried to get (0.0, 0.0) I could **never** get that close vertically. So, this high vertical number truly mystifies me.

Comment: One last tidbit = `.anchorPoint = (0.5, 0.5)`

Comment: **ALMOST THERE** (1) change "let" to "var" + (2) add `location.x = -roomWidth/2 + location.x` & `location.y = roomHeight/2 - location.y` which together changes the `view` coordinates of the original `location` to match the `node.location`. I know I am on the right track because besides the "horse", I have several buildings and 2 people added directly to the `.sks` file. An appropriate `print("\(node.name)")` prints the names of the buildings + people. **BUT**, this does **not** work for my `itsCreditsNode` since this node is programmatically added, versus added to the `.sks` file. **??**

Answer (score 0):

**HERE** is the **THE** answer ...

Make `touchesBegan` an `extension` of `GameScene`, **not** `GameViewController` with:

```
extension GameScene {
        
    // "if we set isUserInteractionEnabled = false, the Scene will receive touch events"
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        //  not needed because addCreditsButton() isn't called
        //  unless we're staring at "GameScene"
    //  if let ourScene = GameScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") {
            
            if let touch:UITouch = touches.first {
                let location = touch.location(in: self)
                let ourNode:SKNode = atPoint(location)   // not ourScene.atPoint(location)
                
            //  print("location = \(location)")
                print("ourNode.name = \(ourNode.name!)")
                if (ourNode.name == "creditsInfo") {
                    showCredits()
                }
            }   // if let touch:UITouch
            
    //  }   // if let ourScene
        
    }   // touchesBegan
```

Comment: All the struggling was a good thing because now I will remember the solution for a very, very long time.